# Can't import some modules in angular 6

Tags: angular, import, rxjs, observable

Trying to import some observable modules in angular 6.
this is the modules i'm trying to import:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";
import { observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { of } from "rxjs/observable/of";
```

I get this error:

```
    ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/BehaviorSubject.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/BehaviorSubject'.
node_modules/rxjs/Rx.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/of.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/observable/of'.
src/app/services/log.service.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/mendi/OneDrive/Desktop/Websites/training/Udemy Course angular/sandbox/devlogger/node_modules/rxjs/BehaviorSubject"' has no exported member 'BehaviorSubject'.
src/app/services/log.service.ts(4,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/mendi/OneDrive/Desktop/Websites/training/Udemy Course angular/sandbox/devlogger/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
src/app/services/log.service.ts(5,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/mendi/OneDrive/Desktop/Websites/training/Udemy Course angular/sandbox/devlogger/node_modules/rxjs/observable/of"' has no exported member 'of'.

ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/BehaviorSubject.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/BehaviorSubject'.
node_modules/rxjs/Rx.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/of.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/observable/of'.
src/app/services/log.service.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/mendi/OneDrive/Desktop/Websites/training/Udemy Course angular/sandbox/devlogger/node_modules/rxjs/BehaviorSubject"' has no exported member 'BehaviorSubject'.
src/app/services/log.service.ts(4,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/mendi/OneDrive/Desktop/Websites/training/Udemy Course angular/sandbox/devlogger/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
src/app/services/log.service.ts(5,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/mendi/OneDrive/Desktop/Websites/training/Udemy Course angular/sandbox/devlogger/node_modules/rxjs/observable/of"' has no exported member 'of'.
```

some info about my version:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.10    

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

can't compile.

what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of } from "rxjs";
```

Comment: Worked. Why is that so?

Comment: check the index file under node_modules/rxjs, this is where all the exports resides. operators are inside node_modules/rxjs/operators